# How to bind SelectedIndex to Textblock on Listbox?

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox, selectedindex

The ListboxItems (lbi) of my listbox contain 2 Textblocks. The first Textblock contains my content. When a user selects an item I want to show the SelectedIndex (so the integer) in the other textblock. So if a user selects items, it will show 1 on the first selected lbi, 2 on the second, and so on...

So I think I need to bind the SelectedIndex to the textblock somehow.

Preferably I want to do this in the datatemplate so I can re-use it on multiple listboxes.

Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: SelectedIndex is zero bound. I.e first element has index = 0.

Comment: Better add some code (XAML) that demonstrates what you are trying to do. If the listbox just contains two TextBlocks the selected index can only be -1, 0 or 1, right?

Comment: The ListBoxItemTemplate consists of 2 textboxes. The number of items is undefined. The first Textbox of each ListboxItem shows its content. The second Textbox is supposed to show the SelectedIndex.